# Efficiently Iterate over large list of photos in iOS shortcut

Tags: ios, photos.app, shortcuts-app

I'm writing an iOS shortcut to iterate over all of my photos and upload them to a server (POST request). Below is a repeat block that uploads the photos one at a time to the server.

[image: Shortcut iterating over photos]

For small amounts of images (~20) this works pretty well, iterating over the list and uploading the files quickly. However, for large amounts of images (>1000), **each iteration of the loop** takes upwards of a minute to simply access the image, even without the POST request. So with a larger input size, not only are there more iterations but each iteration takes very long. Is this because accessing a single photo from the list of photos is not an O(1) operation, even in a repeat with each item loop? How can one iterate over a very large list of  Photos in Shortcuts without running into performance issues? Here is an [example ios shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/a8dd623d0925420bbd04d10f4c237711) that iterates over photos. I tested this on my iPhone running iOS 17.1

Specifically, is this iteration slow because the shortcut is written inefficiently or because getting the Repeat Item for a large list in iOS shortcuts is an expensive operation? If it's the latter, are there alternative ways of iterating over the photos faster, maybe by converting them to a dictionary or other structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've modified it to be more specific to what I'm curious about